# How do I identify like sets using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-intelligence

Using SQL Server, I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

What I need to do is write a query to identify scenarios where the Name and Permissions field are equal so that I can give give them a unique Set ID.

For instance, rows 2 and 4 would be a set I can give a SetID as well as rows 6 and 7 are a set that I can give another SetID. But rows 2 and 3 are NOT a set.

So far I have tried using `DENSE_RANK () Over(Order by Name)` which helps to add an id based on like Names but doesn't take into account matching permissions. And have tried joining the table on itself but with millions of rows of data I end up with unwanted duplicates.

The logic I am following is this:

If (Name and Permissions) of one row = (Name and Permissions) of another row give them a SetID to share.

Please help I have been banging my head against the wall with this one. Ideally a SQL query would accomplish this but am open to anything.

Thank you!

Comment: You want want to look at `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name,Permissions ORDER BY .....)` - that would "partition" your data by the `(Name, Permissions)` combination and hand out numbers starting from 1 for each partition - so if you have a partition with multiple entries, that number would go 1, 2, 3, .... and so on and you can easily identify those "duplicate" entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it for example like this:

```
select
  Name,
  Permission,
  row_number() over (order by Name, Permission) as RN
from (
  select distinct
    Name,
    Permission
  from
    permissions
) TMP
order by Name, Permission
```

The inner select gets the distinct combinations, and the outer one assigns the numbers.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8319/3

Comment: I used your sample query but with DENSE_Rank instead as I want to be able to see the duplicates. Any ideas how to find the rows with the same SetID and tag one in the set of like ID's based upon a value in another column. For instance, 4 rows with SetID X I want to tag one of the 4 with "Primary" based on a value from another column?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably do something similar to what you want.

```
SELECT 
   name,
   permissions,
   accountname,   
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,permissions ORDER By name,permissions) as SetID
FROM table;
```